# Reversing Decimal to Binary Conversion Result

Tags: c++, binary, integer

I'm trying to convert integers to binary, using the modulo operator. I get the correct digits, although they are in the incorrect order. For example 76 to binary is `1001100` but the output is `0011001`; hence, I have tried to rectify this by outputting `1` if the result is `0` and outputting out `0` if the result is `1`, using if-else statements; but the result is then `1100110`, which is also wrong.

Here is my code:

```cpp
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num;
    int remainder;

    cout << "Enter a decimal number:" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    
    while (num != 0){
        remainder = num % 2;
        if (remainder == 1 ){
            cout << remainder - 1;
        }
        else if (remainder == 0){
            cout << remainder + 1;
        }
        num = num / 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*I'm trying to convert integers to binary*" Why? Integers already *are* binary. You're trying to convert your integer to a decimal equivalent of what the binary will look like in another integer... What's the end goal here? Why do you need this instead of just using the int as-is or sticking it in a binary character string?

Comment: @scohe001 I think it's quite clear that the OP wants to *print* the value(s) in binary.

Comment: You need to reverse the order in which the digits are printed, not swap 0 and 1.

Comment: if you have `101010000` and want to reverse it, thats `000010101` flipping the bits is `010100000`, thats not the same

Comment: Put your digits in a container!  Then you have **many** options, and many answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than flipping the individual output digits, you need to reverse their order. There are many ways you can do this but one quite 'natural' method is to use a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) – which is an inherently last-in, first-out (LIFO) system.

The [C++ Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) provides a [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) container, ready-to-use. Here's a working program that does what you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using std::cout, std::cin, std::endl; // Pre-C++17, these will need to be separate "using" lines!
using std::stack;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int remainder;
    stack<char> digits;

    cout << "Enter a decimal number:" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while (num != 0) { // Push the digits onto the stack ...
        remainder = num % 2;
        digits.push(remainder ? '1' : '0');
        num = num / 2;
    }
    while (!digits.empty()) { // ... then print and pop them (in reverse order)
        cout << digits.top();
        digits.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why does flipping the output does not work? Im still trying to get my head around that

Comment: @Yusuf Flipping the output digits does nothing to correct the fact that they are in the wrong order (i.e. they are reversed). So, if your real answer should be `1001100` but you get `0011001`, how does flipping correct the reversal? The two 'errors' don't cancel each other out. The "wrong order" problem is inherent in your method: you are analysing the `num` value 'from the bottom up' (i.e. starting with the **least significant** binary digit and working upwards); but Western-style numbers (left-to-right scripts) print the **most significant** digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::bitset`. But if you want to do this without using `std::bitset`, you can push bits to string and reverse it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string

Solution without Bitset

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  int N, i = 0; 
  
  std::cout << "Enter a decimal number:" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> N;

  std::string res(32, '0');
  while (N) {
    res[i++] += (N&1);
    N >>= 1;  
  }

  std::reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
  std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Solution With Bitset

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
  int N; 
  
  std::cout << "Enter a decimal number:" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> N;

  std::cout << std::bitset<32>(N).to_string() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not initialize `i = 31` and then do `res[i--] += (N & 1);` in the loop? Then you don't need the call to `std:reverse`.

Comment: @AdrianMole If you want you can do like that :)